# Subdomain tracking during AB testing in Google Analytics

Tags: testing, google-analytics, analytics

I am running AB testing on the category pages of www.gunnars.com and I see **inflated referral data coming from the homepage**.
Currently subdomain tracking is enabled, as the site has multiple sub domains including for one checkout. We use Tealium as a tag manager and the GA code looks like this in Tealium:
What are we doing wrong?

```
//tealium universal tag - utag.sender.7001 ut4.0.##UTVERSION##, Copyright ##UTYEAR## Tealium.com Inc. All Rights Reserved.
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
try{
(function(id,loader,u){
  try{u=utag.o[loader].sender[id]={}}catch(e){u=utag.sender[id]};
  u.ev={'view':1,'link':1};
  u.max_custom=10;
  u.clearVar=function(){for(var i=1;i<=u.max_custom;i++){_gaq.push([u.prefix+'_deleteCustomVar',i])}};
  u.domain="##UTVARconfig_domain##" || utag.loader.lh();
  u.prefix="##UTVARconfig_prefix##";
  u.prefix=((u.prefix)?u.prefix+'.':'');
  u.ga1="##UTVARconfig_accountprimary##";
  u.setallowlinker=##UTVARconfig_setallowlinker##;
  u.inpage_linkid=##UTVARconfig_inpagelinkid##;
  if(u.inpage_linkid){_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js'])};
  _gaq.push([u.prefix+'_setAccount',u.ga1]);
  u.anonymizeIp="##UTVARconfig_anonymizeip##";
  if(u.anonymizeIp==="true"){_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp'])};
  _gaq.push([u.prefix+'_setDomainName',u.domain]);
  if(u.setallowlinker || u.domain=='none'){_gaq.push([u.prefix+'_setAllowLinker', true])};
##UTGEN##
  u.send=function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){
    if(u.ev[a]||typeof u.ev.all!="undefined"){
      u.a=a;
      ##UTEXTEND##
      for(c in utag.loader.GV(b)){if(typeof u.map[c+":"+b[c]]!="undefined"){b[c+":"+b[c]]=b[c]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Universal Analytics, in addition to not needing to change the tracking script for subdomains you can create filtered views like so:  https://coderwall.com/p/ygzyfg

Essentially:  Admin > View (+create new) > Filters (+new) > "include only" + "traffic to the hostname" + "that contain" + 'subdomain.host.com'